# transaction stuck in txpool as pending

Tags: pending-transactions, txpool, ethereumjs-tx

I have a geth node, and using truffle-hd-wallet. I am trying to create a transaction between coinbase and the account created by hd-wallet.Created a raw transaction and signed it with privatekey of coinbase. The transaction is stuck in txpool in pending state.
Transaction object created as:

```
{
        'from': <coinbase account>,
        'to': <acc created by hdwallet>,
        'value':1,
        'chainId': <net.getId()>,
        'gasPrice': <eth.getGasPrice>,
        'gasLimit': 2000000
    }
```

Signed with, `web3I.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey)`

web3.txpool.content shows below,

```
{
  pending: {
    0x0C0Df324C081fAF1c9fE6BF98379e0614181d254: {
      0: {
        blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        blockNumber: null,
        from: "0x0c0df324c081faf1c9fe6bf98379e0614181d254",
        gas: "0x1e8480",
        gasPrice: "0x430e23400",
        hash: "0x6c525ad1ed8b128ba04e12e990e762697d9ac093c5342d7a4835318e74bb518f",
        input: "0x",
        nonce: "0x0",
        r: "0x346c40bd758c67f5082976d9e5523f0b171b397d53b30ff6183d31e3314b7ff1",
        s: "0x68bd289133fcf966f71d51fdbe282c176a6b7739f8532d347471183e056352e8",
        to: "0x74f59f7f123fa71a8d0b71d792a6d040bbdd2fdd",
        transactionIndex: "0x0",
        v: "0x9c7",
        value: "0x5"
      }
    }
  },
  queued: {}
}
```

I have tried even including nonce, increasing gasPrice, also using ethereumjs-tx, but same result

Comment: Are you on a private network? What client are you using? ie geth, ganache, parity or other?

Comment: its a single node geth client...

Comment: You need to mine transactions: `miner.start(1)` will start mining and `miner.stop()` to stop.

Comment: the node is mining, i have used --mine option to start geth

Comment: Do you have enough balance in the sender to pay for the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

solved it by removing 'chainId': , from the tx object. Not sure exactly why 'chainId' puts tx in pending state.